# ¿Cómo ordenar un map cuya clave es una clase y su valor un ArrayList de clases?

Tags: java

Si tengo declarado este map:

```
private Map<Asignatura, List<Alumno>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

```
public class Asignatura {
    private String nombre;
    private int codigo;
    private String profesor;
    private String departamento;
}
```

```
public class Alumno {
    private String apellido;
    private String nombre;
    private String correo;
    private String dni;
}
```

y quisiera por ejemplo dada una asignatura (por su código), mostrar la relación de alumnos de esa asignatura (puede estar ordenada por apellidos, nombre o dni). ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

No encuentro ningún ejemplo para ordenar un map cuya clave sea una clase y su valor un ArrayList de clases.

Comment: El `map` no se puede ordenar per se. Lo que puedes tener ordenadas son las entradas, es decir, las llaves. Lo que pides es ordenar los datos por apellido, pero el apellido corresponde a los `Alumno`s que se encuentran en los valores del mapa. Lo que podrías hacer es recorrer todas las entradas del mapa y ordenar las listas tal como deseas. Confírmame si es eso lo que buscas.

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres es ordenar la lista de alumnos para cada asignatura, no el mapa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solucion podría ser esta:

Archivo **Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    private Map<Asignatura, List<Alumno>> map;

    // constructor de la clase Main
    public Main() {
        ArrayList<Alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<>(15);

        // lista de alumnos
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Arenas Bustamante", "Eluhuei", "e.arenas@mail.com", "66565325J"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Valadez Borrego", "Otilia", "o.valadez@mail.com", "31493438K"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Munguia Aguirre", "Nehuén", "n.munguia@mail.com", "99883065E"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Ayala Navarrete", "Ivany", "i.ayala@mail.com", "07109478V"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Villareal Alvarado", "Umbelina", "u.villareal@mail.com", "61831108R"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Acuna Vanegas", "Onofre", "o.acuna@mail.com", "30396046M"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Solorio Becerra", "Karen", "k.solorio@mail.com", "23626376V"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Olivera Barrientos", "Queta", "q.olivera@mail.com", "45938196C"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Estrada Sosa", "Thina", "t.estrada@mail.com", "34688652Y"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Pabón Santacruz", "Frutos", "f.pabón@mail.com", "33923603Y"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Gurule Valladares", "Vesta", "v.gurule@mail.com", "20415549J"));
        alumnos.add(new Alumno("Fonseca Puga", "Yosef", "y.fonseca@mail.com", "33950708V"));

        Asignatura asignatura1 = new Asignatura("Lenguaje", 1, "Pedro Picapiedra", "Departamento 1");

        // añadir al mapa la asignatura y los alumnos creados
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(asignatura1, alumnos);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // crear un ejemplar de esta clase
        Main ejemplo = new Main();

        // imprimir por la salida estandar el arreglo
        System.out.println(ejemplo.map.get(new Asignatura(1)));

        // ordenar el arreglo
        Collections.sort(ejemplo.map.get(new Asignatura(1)));

        // imprimir el arreglo ordenado
        System.out.println(ejemplo.map.get(new Asignatura(1)));
    }
}
```

Archivo **Alumno.java**

```
public class Alumno implements Comparable<Alumno> {

    private String apellido;
    private String nombre;
    private String correo;
    private String dni;

    public Alumno(String apellido, String nombre, String correo, String dni) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alumno o) {
        String alumno1 = this.apellido.toLowerCase() + this.nombre.toLowerCase();
        String alumno2 = o.apellido.toLowerCase() + o.nombre.toLowerCase();

        return alumno1.compareTo(alumno2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }
}
```

Archivo **Asignatura.java**

```
public class Asignatura {

    private String nombre;
    private int codigo;
    private String profesor;
    private String departamento;

    public Asignatura(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Asignatura(String nombre, int codigo, String profesor, String departamento) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.profesor = profesor;
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return (obj instanceof Asignatura) && ((Asignatura) obj).codigo == this.codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.codigo;
    }
}
```

La clase `Alumno` debe implementar la interfaz `Comparable`. Esto le permite a `Alumno` poder ser ordenado. El metodo `toString()` se sobrescribe para imprimir bien en la linea `System.out.println(ejemplo.map.get(...));`

En la clase `Asignatura` se sobrescribe el `equals()` y el `hashCode()` para lograr que la `key` del mapa `private Map<Asignatura, List<Alumno>> map;` sea el código de la asignatura y permita usar `map.get(new Asignatura(1))`

Todos los *[nombres](http://es.fakenamegenerator.com/advanced.php?t=country&n%5B%5D=sp&c%5B%5D=sp&gen=50&age-min=19&age-max=85)* y *[DNIs](http://niednicifgenerador.appspot.com/)* fueron generados aleatoriamente.

Tomé como referencia

- [Java ArrayList of Object Sort Example](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-of-object-sort-example-comparable-and-comparator/)
- [How to make java HashMap work properly with custom Key type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039222/how-to-make-java-hashmap-work-properly-with-custom-key-type)

Comment: No consigo que funcione el código. ¿Por qué hay que poner  `Collections.sort(ejemplo.map.get(new Asignatura(1)));`? Yo he añadido al map varias asignaturas. Me da el error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

Comment: `Collections.sort` sirve para ordenar un array list. Probablemente tu clase asignatura no ha implementado `equals()` y `hashCode()`

Comment: Con `ejemplo.map.get(new Asignatura(1))` digo que llame a la fucion get de la variable map(que es el mapa que contiene la asignatura). Pero para ello creo una asignatura que tenga el codigo 1 con `new asignatura(1)`, no he encontrado otra forma de referirse a `map.get(miAsignatura)` sin tener que pasar el mismo objeto que se agregó al mapa. ya que si creas una nueva asignatura probablemente al hacer `miAsignatura.equals(nuevaAsignatura)` no devolverá true al no ser la misma instancia. Si tienes una mejor forma de acceder a la asignatura que está en el mapa sin usar el mismo objeto, Muestrame